# Using two LIKE's in different columnName?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm trying to make a search function in JTable in my program, but i got sql syntax error when i use this syntax. I've been read much question and answer in this problem and i never got the right syntax. Hope you can help me.

```
private void fillTable(String keyword) throws SQLException{
    if (!keyword.equals("")){
        try( Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
                            ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?zero"
                                    + "DateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM basis"
                    + "WHERE barcode LIKE '%"+keyword+"%' or "
                    + "namaProduk LIKE '% "+keyword+" %'");               
        ){
            jTable1.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
        }  
    }
    else fillTable();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing 1 space between `basis` and `WHERE` (reason for the syntax error).

There is 1 unwanted space between `%` and your keyword (makes your query irrelevant).

```
private void fillTable(String keyword) throws SQLException{
    if (!keyword.equals("")){
        try( Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
                            ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?zero"
                                    + "DateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM basis "
                    + "WHERE barcode LIKE '%"+keyword+"%' or "
                    + "namaProduk LIKE '%"+keyword+" %'");               
        ){
            jTable1.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
        }  
    }
    else fillTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can see here is that there's a space missing behind the table name "basis". Generally, you should test your SQL statements manually via an existing DB client and then copy them into your code.

If you're open to tools that will ease your pain, try [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/).